# Is there a way to do per-application rules in pfctl/alf?

Tags: firewall, ipfw

I'd like to implement a mitmproxy for a single application on my mac. Pfctl doesn't natively have (from what I can see) support to set rules based on the application source/dest of the packets, but the Application Level Filter (ALF) does. Is there a way to combine the two? From what I can see, the only rules you can apply to ALF is a simple accept/deny flag, nothing more. I'd ideally like to apply a 'rdr' rule within alf

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this [post](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/336) (see comment dated 30 Aug from user mhils)?  Basically, running in mitmproxy in transparent mode can be accomplished with the -T argument.  It appears that this is supposed to provide access to the PID of the source process, but I am not sure that the destination process id is captured.

I am not a user of mitmproxy, so please let me know if this helps.

Cheers,
Byron